# ruby's json schema validator - dealing with required, optional and undefined fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, validation, schema

I'm using json-schema in ruby to do this check.

```
schema = {
      "type" => "object",
      "properties" => {
          "id" => {"type": "string"},
          "experience" => {"type": "array"},
          "education" => {"type": "string"}
      },
      "required" => ["id", "education"]
  }

JSON::Validator.validate!(schema, {"id" => 1, "education" => "MIT", "new_field":"dummy"})
```

I would like the validation to fail as there is a "new_field" which is not defined in the schema. However it doesn't fail as the validation seems to be happy that the required field is present.

```
 JSON::Validator.validate!(schema, {"id" => 1, "education" => "MIT", "new_field":"dummy"},:strict => true)
```

If I use strict option it complains about "experience" along with "new_field", which I don't like. I would like to complain only when it finds any undefined keys not mentioned in the original schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like the validation to fail as there is a "new_field" which is not defined in the schema.

So you want the validation to fail when **additional properties** outside the schema are present.

Add `"additionalProperties" => false` to your schema to achieve this. And don't use the `strict` option.

In details. let the schema be:

```
schema = {
    "type" => "object",
    "properties" => {
        "id" => {"type": "string"},
        "experience" => {"type": "array"},
        "education" => {"type": "string"}
    },
    "required" => ["id", "education"],
    "additionalProperties" => false
}
```

And this validation is gonna fail:

```
JSON::Validator.validate!(schema, {"id" => '1', "education" => "MIT", "new_field":"dummy"})
```

But this won't:

```
JSON::Validator.validate!(schema, {"id" => '1', "education" => "MIT"})
```

Note that i adjusted `id` to be `String` not `FixNum`.